# Rails routes option "as", can't edit resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application I have model "Regulation", form for creating regulations looks like this:

```
- if %W(edit update).include? action_name
  = content_for :heading, t('partners.regulations.edit')
- else
  = content_for :heading,  t('partners.regulations.new')
.row
  .col-md-6
    = horizontal_simple_form_for [:partners, @regulation] do |f|
      = f.error_notification
      %ul.nav.nav-pills
        %li
          = link_to image_tag("flag_pl.png"), '#PL', class: 'regulation_pl'
        %li
          = link_to image_tag("flag_en.png"), '#EN', class: 'regulation_en'
      .polish_regulation
        %h1.page-header
          = t('partners.regulations.polish')      
        = f.input :content_pl, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Pure', width: 750} }, error: false
      .english_regulation
        %h1.page-header
          = t('partners.regulations.english')       
        = f.input :content_en, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Basic', width: 750} }, error: false    
      - if %W(edit update).include? action_name
        = f.submit t('actions.save_changes'), class: "btn btn-lg btn-default"
      - else
        = f.submit t('partners.regulations.save'), class: "btn btn-lg btn-default"
```

In my routes I have:

```
namespace :partners do
  resources :regulations, as: :rental_company_regulation, except: :show
end
```

My controller looks like this:

```
module Partners
  class RegulationsController < ApplicationController
    include Partners::BaseController
    load_and_authorize_resource through: :rental_company, singleton: true

    before_action :set_breadcrumbs
    before_action :set_regulation, only: :new

    def new
      if @rental_company_regulation
        redirect_to  edit_partners_rental_company_regulation_path(@rental_company_regulation)
      end
      add_breadcrumb t('partners.regulations.new')
    end

    def create
      if @regulation.save
        flash[:notice] = t('partners.regulations.created')
        redirect_to partners_root_path
      else
        add_breadcrumb t('partners.regulations.new')
        render :new
      end
    end


    def edit
      add_breadcrumb t('partners.regulations.edit')
    end

    def update
      if @regulation.update(regulation_params)
        flash[:notice] = t('partners.regulations.updated')
        redirect_to partners_root_path
      else  
        add_breadcrumb t('partners.regulations.edit')
        render :edit
      end
    end

    protected

    def set_regulation
      @rental_company_regulation = Regulation.where(rental_company_id: rental_company).first
    end

    def set_breadcrumbs
      add_breadcrumb current_partner.rental_company.name, :partners_root_path
    end

    private

    def regulation_params
      params.require(:regulation).permit(:content_pl, :content_en, :rental_company_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Creating resource from scratch works properly. But I went to: 
`"http://localhost:3000/partners/regulations/4/edit"` to edit regulation I have the following error:

```
undefined method `partners_regulation_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000000242fae8>:0x00000007d9afb0>
```

I can't solve this problem. What's wrong?

Edit:

Rake routes:

```
partners_rental_company_regulation_index GET      /partners/regulations(.:format)                                         partners/regulations#index
                                         POST     /partners/regulations(.:format)                                         partners/regulations#create
  new_partners_rental_company_regulation GET      /partners/regulations/new(.:format)                                     partners/regulations#new
 edit_partners_rental_company_regulation GET      /partners/regulations/:id/edit(.:format)                                partners/regulations#edit
      partners_rental_company_regulation PATCH    /partners/regulations/:id(.:format)                                     partners/regulations#update
```

Edit2:
I've changed my form too looks like this:

```
= horizontal_simple_form_for [:partners, @regulation], url: partners_rental_company_regulation_path
```

Now I can edit exisiting resource but can't create a new one. When I trying to create the new one I have the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"partners/regulations"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

What's wrong?

Comment: can you post your rake routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**as**

To simplify `user2675613`'s answer, your error is basically caused by using the [`as` argument](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes) in your routes

`as:` basically allows you to "name" the route:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users               # -> users_path
resources :users, as: :members # -> members_path
```

---

**Error**

Your error is as follows:

```
undefined method `partners_regulation_path'
```

This basically means you're using a path which doesn't exist. This is because you've used the `as:` option in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :partners do
   resources :regulations #-> partners_regulation_path
end

resources :partners do
   resources :regulations, as: "test" # -> partners_test_path
end
```

This is confirmed with your routes:

```
partners_rental_company_regulation_index
new_partners_rental_company_regulation
edit_partners_rental_company_regulation    
partners_rental_company_regulation
```

---

**Fix**

The way to fix this is to remove the `as:` option from your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :partners do
   resources :regulations #-> partner_regulations_path
end
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to keep the custom `name` for your paths, you'll have to change your path references to `parental_company_regulation_path`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see you in your rake routes your url to edit a regulation is `edit_partners_rental_company_regulation GET      /partners/regulations/:id/edit(.:format)` and to create a new one the url is `new_partners_rental_company_regulation GET      /partners/regulations/new(.:format)`.

You need to change the way you are using your form here. You can create a partial for all the common fields of form but you need to separate the url part in your form to make a create and update requests.

You can make a partial `_form.html.haml` with contents:

```
= f.error_notification
  %ul.nav.nav-pills
    %li
      = link_to image_tag("flag_pl.png"), '#PL', class: 'regulation_pl'
    %li
      = link_to image_tag("flag_en.png"), '#EN', class: 'regulation_en'
  .polish_regulation
    %h1.page-header
      = t('partners.regulations.polish')      
    = f.input :content_pl, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Pure', width: 750} }, error: false
  .english_regulation
    %h1.page-header
      = t('partners.regulations.english')       
    = f.input :content_en, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'Basic', width: 750} }, error: false
```

Then inside your `edit.html.haml` you can have:

```
= content_for :heading, t('partners.regulations.edit')
  .row
    .col-md-6
      = horizontal_simple_form_for [:partners, @regulation], url: partners_rental_company_regulation_path  do |f|
        = render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f }  #you need to pass other required locals too else it'll give error 
        = f.submit t('actions.save_changes'), class: "btn btn-lg btn-default"
```

Similarly inside your `new.html.haml` you can have:

```
= content_for :heading,  t('partners.regulations.new')
  .row
    .col-md-6
      = horizontal_simple_form_for [:partners, @regulation], url: partners_rental_company_regulation_index_path  do |f|
        = render :partial => "form", :locals => { :f => f } #you need to pass other required locals too else it'll give error
        = f.submit t('partners.regulations.save'), class: "btn btn-lg btn-default"
```